# Git - detect if branch has no changes after rebase

Tags: git

Is there any tool/trick to improve this workflow:

```
⋊> on master ◦ git branch -d add_code_to_import_from_mew       
error: The branch 'add_code_to_import_from_mew' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D add_code_to_import_from_mew'.

⋊> on master ◦ git checkout add_code_to_import_from_mew                                               Switched to branch 'add_code_to_import_from_mew'

⋊> on add_code_to_import_from_mew  git rebase master 
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

⋊> on add_code_to_import_from_mew  git checkout master                                            21:13:22
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

⋊> on master ◦ git branch -d add_code_to_import_from_mew                                          21:13:33
Deleted branch add_code_to_import_from_mew (was ed05c05).
```

I do not want to use "-D" - just want to delete when there are no changes

Comment: What do you mean by "no changes"?

Comment: empty diff to master

Comment: And you want to delete _all_ the local branches that don't differ from `master`?

Comment: yes and even some that differ from master but just in commits - not diff

Comment: You write "I do not want to use '-D'" but you may need to if the branches in question are not fully contained into `master`... Do you just want a script to automate deletions of those branches?

Comment: the steps I am stating in the question as a script would be fine with me - just think something like this must already exist or is just hidden behind some CLI option that I do not (yet) know - hence asking

Comment: There is no built-in command for bulk deletion of branches, but you could write a script that does what you want using `git for-each-ref` and `git diff-index`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - will still wait a bit before writing a script as I think something like this might already exist and I do not want to keep things DRY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following (POSIX-compliant) script will delete all local branches that have empty diffs against `master`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
  while read ref; do
    test $ref != master && \
      git diff-tree --quiet $ref master && \
      git branch -D $ref
  done
```

Use with caution! An empty diff with `master` doesn't imply that the branch is fully merged in `master`!